# 'Try without catch error', ')' expected, illegal start of expression..?

Tags: android, try-catch

I'm getting these errors in the ending curly brackets in the code below. Can someone tell me why these errors are coming up? I thought code was meant to end with curly brackets.

```
      String line = "";
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        buffer.append(line);
                    }

                    movieData.setText(buffer.toString());

                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    //will check if connection is running or not and will disconnect accordingly
                    if (connection != null) {
                        connection.disconnect();
                    }
                    try {
                        try {
                            reader.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add a `catch` **block** at the end:

```
try {
    try {
        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
catch (Exception e) { // Add catch block to handle potential exception
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

(taking in consideration that you started with a `try` **block** at the beginning, before `String line = "";`)

Comment: can i ask one more question pls? logcat is saying saying that '}' at the end of my code is wrong and a ) or ; is expected. why is this?

Comment: Simple formatting errors : go through your code for any missing parentheses or curly braces.